# Rebind emmet-mode to smart-tab

Tags: key-bindings

I have emmet-mode installed and smart-tab installed and I want to rebind the  default  C-j of  emmet to smart-tabs TAB.

```
(require 'emmet-mode)
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode) ;; Auto-start on any markup modes
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook  'emmet-mode) ;; enable Emmet's css abbreviation.
(setq emmet-move-cursor-between-quotes t) ;; default nil

(require 'smart-tab)
(global-smart-tab-mode 1)
(define-key emmet-expand-line [(tab)] 'smart-tab)

;;; http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabCompletion
(defun hippie-unexpand ()
  (interactive)
  (hippie-expand 0))

(define-key read-expression-map [(shift tab)] 'hippie-unexpand)
```

This is the error

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Users/Sayth/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/init.el':

Symbol's value as variable is void: emmet-expand-line
```

I am copying the format from here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Remapping-Commands but I appear to be getting it wrong.

```
(define-key my-mode-map [remap kill-line] 'my-kill-line)
```

and this action is what is advised by the  package  author https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode

> press C-j to expand it (or alternatively, alias your preferred
>   keystroke to M-x emmet-expand-line)

Comment: Are you trying to bind `emmet-expand-line` to `TAB`, or trying to make it one of the actions which `smart-tab` executes some of the time? In the latter case, it matters which particular implementation of smart-tab you're using.

Comment: It is the later.https://github.com/genehack/smart-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/genehack/smart-tab provides [`smart-tab-completion-functions-alist`](https://github.com/genehack/smart-tab/blob/7926b478bd225ef4aafe8842b7d442f4b301a9ba/smart-tab.el#L79) for adding per mode actions. It doesn't check parent modes, so to make it work for `sgml-mode` and all derivatives we can add an entry in the mode hook:

```
(require 'smart-tab)
(global-smart-tab-mode 1)

(defun add-emmet-expand-to-smart-tab-completions ()
  ;; Add an entry for current major mode in
  ;; `smart-tab-completion-functions-alist' to use
  ;; `emmet-expand-line'.
  (add-to-list 'smart-tab-completion-functions-alist
               (cons major-mode #'emmet-expand-line)))   

(require 'emmet-mode)
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode) ;; Auto-start on any markup modes
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'add-emmet-expand-to-smart-tab-completions)
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook  'emmet-mode) ;; enable Emmet's css abbreviation.
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'add-emmet-expand-to-smart-tab-completions)
...
```

---

> and this action is what is advised by the package author https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode
>
> > press C-j to expand it (or alternatively, alias your preferred keystroke to M-x emmet-expand-line)

They meant something like `(define-key emmet-mode-keymap [tab] 'emmet-expand-line)`, but that would take over the tab key and you wouldn't be using `smart-tab` anymore.